# How to create specific dictionaries from other iterables using for loops?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I want to create a dictionary using an iterable which has multiple iterables in itself as well.

I tried:

```
def setdict(list = ["hello", "world", "something", "foo"])
    for i in list:
        dict = {i[0]:i}
    return dict
print setdict(list = ["hello", "world", "something", "foo"])
```

I expect an output like:

```
{"h":"hello", "w":"world", "s":"something", "f":"foo"}
```

but the actual output is:

```
{'f': 'foo'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `dict` comprehension

**Ex:**

```
def setdict(lst = ["hello", "world", "something", "foo"]):
    return {i[0]:i for i in lst}
print setdict(lst = ["hello", "world", "something", "foo"])
```

**Output:**

```
{'h': 'hello', 's': 'something', 'w': 'world', 'f': 'foo'}
```

In your case you are over-writing the dictionary in each loop.

Comment: While the input list isn't being modified in this case, it may be helpful for a beginner to point out that [mutable default arguments](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) can be dangerous as well

Answer (score 3):

Here:

`dict = {i[0]:i}`

you are creating a new dictionary each time.

Declare it first and then update:

```
result = {}
for i in items:
    result[i[0]] = i
return result
```

The comprehension given by the other answer is also good.

By the way, you shouldn't use `dict` or `list` as variable names. It's a built-in word, so you will break your program in mysterious ways.

Using a list as a default argument will also lead to [awful surprising errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: Yes, the code is not directly from my program; I am aware of the fact that built-in names should not be used as variable names or parameters. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your for-loop recreates the whole dict() on every iteration: `dict = {i[0]:i}` -leaving you with the last value.

Your (working) implementation would make this

```
print setdict(["hello", "world", "something", "foo", "hello - 2"])
```

to

```
{"h":"hello - 2", "w":"world", "s":"something", "f":"foo"}
```

loosing the first `"hello"`.

---

It may be better to use a defaultdict to avoid overwriting duplicates:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def setdict(l): # dont do l = []  - it has ramifications
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for i in l:
        d[i[0]].append(i)

    return dict(d)

print setdict(["hello", "world", "something", "foo", "hello - 2"])
```

Output:

```
{'h': ['hello', 'hello - 2'], 's': ['something'], 'w': ['world'], 'f': ['foo']}
```

---

**Other remarks & ramifications:**

- do not call variables after built ins - they shadow them:

  ```
  k = str(5)
  str = 22
  o = str(5)  # crash - the str-function is shadowed
  ```
- avoid default params that are references:

```
def k(l=[]): # reference default param, keeps values
    l.append(0)         # over different calls of the function
        return l 

    print(k())
    print(k())
    print(k())
    print(k())
    print(k())
```

```
[0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)